# MySQL Left Join With Three Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that requires what I think is a complicated JOIN.  I have three tables that are sort of "children" of each other.  The top table is "clan_members".  The next is "roster_members" which gets the clan_member id.  The bottom one is "match_players" which gets the roster_members id. I wrote a loop that takes me through all of the results in the clan_members table.  What I want to do is find out how many matches that clan member has played in.  Here's the layouts of the three tables:

```
[clan_members]
     -id
     - member_id
     -join_date

[roster_members]
     - id
     - clan_member_id
     - title

[match_players]
     - id
     - roster_member_id
     - match_id
```

I have never done a JOIN  with three different tables before and I have no idea what order to do them in.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could write me a query!

Comment: Order doesn't matter, and the SO community prefers that you demonstrate that you've tried something before asking.

Comment: @OMGPonies: For `INNER JOIN`, no. For `LEFT JOIN`, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will get you the number of matches that clan member with id 123 has participated in:

```
select count(*) as match_count
from clan_members c, roster_members r, match_players m
where c.member_id = r.clan_member_id
and r.id = m.roster_member_id
and c.id = 123
```

On a side note, it would be good practice to name your columns consistently. For example, all columns that have the clan_member_id should be named the same. In the clan_members table its called id but in the roster_members table its called clan_member_id. Just makes it easier to understand how the tables join together.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT match_id 
  FROM clan_members 
    INNER JOIN roster_members 
      ON clan_members.id = roster_members.clan_member_id 
    INNER JOIN match_players 
      ON roster_members.id = match_players.roster_member_id;
```

will get you the # of unique `match_id`s when all three tables are joined.